# Как изменить метод класса в папке Vendor?

Tags: laravel

Я знаю, что ничего в Vendor менять нельзя. Я переопределял методы аутентификации, но там уже была готовая инфраструктура (я просто добавлял свои методы в контроллеры регистрации). Я прочитал много инфы в Интернете, но везде только общие слова. Где можно увидеть пример переопределения метода? Я могу создать свой класс, наследовать изменяемый класс, добавить свой измененный метод, но:

1)  пишут, что так делать неправильно и нужно использовать свои какие-то контейнеры зависимостей

2)  Я не буду потом обращаться к методу. К нему будет обращаться тот класс, метод которого я хочу изменить. А значит мое наследование ему должно быть побарабану – моего класса оно не видит и не знает.

В общем, тема важная и интересная, добавляйте свои примеры изменения метода в Vendor или ссылки на примеры с картинками, не стесняйтесь)

ПРИМЕР:
В Vendor есть класс Agent, к которому я обращаюсь через

```
Если $agent->browser() !== 'Safari' то..
```

То есть вызываю функцию browser

```
public function browser($userAgent = null)
{
    return $this->findDetectionRulesAgainstUA(static::getBrowsers(), $userAgent);
}
```

Которая вызывает функцию findDetectionRulesAgainstUA

```
protected function findDetectionRulesAgainstUA(array $rules, $userAgent = null)
{
    // Loop given rules
    foreach ($rules as $key => $regex) {
        if (empty($regex)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Check match
        if ($this->match($regex, $userAgent)) {
            return $key ?: reset($this->matchesArray);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

В которую я хочу внести изменения. Как это сделать?

Comment: нужно было форкнуть требуемый пакет на гитхабе, подключить свой репозиторий с этим пакетом, а  потом уже изменять его.

Comment: Тема действительно интересная, но ни фига не понятно. Приведите свой пример, а то в вопросе только общие слова.

Comment: Не вижу ничего плохого, чтобы наследовать вендор-классы и переопределять методы. Половина Yii разработчиков так делают xD (и я)

Comment: @РустамГимранов добавил пример

Comment: @Skywave как это сделать на основе примера который я привел? проблема в том, что мне нужно изменить функцию, которая вызывается классом Agent

Comment: @Alex, К сожалению с laravel не имел дело, не могу подсказать. Например в Yii у компонента в конфиге можно указать класс, который его реализует (его мы подменяем). Мжб в laravel есть что-то похожее